# Rate limit for libspotify

Tags: spotify

I just started to observe the following error message from [CocoaLibSpotify didLogMessage] in my iOS App.

I [snd:381] Rate limited. Waiting 3s

Does anyone know what the libspotify API rate limit is?  I saw that the web API limit is 10/second/IP. Is is the same for libspotify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

libspotify APIs are executed on your local machine - there's no rate limit in calling them.

You've provided pretty much zero context for this, but I *think* what you're seeing is that you're playing a track and CocoaLibSpotify has filled a playback buffer. libSpotify won't give audio data at faster than 1.5x realtime, so it's waiting before it tries to refill the buffer.

That message is perfectly normal, and the "I" in front of it means it's only an informational message.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that message in the normal Linux desktop client as well. I only get it when I am browsing music and I skip too many tracks too quickly. There is a server side rate limit of how fast you can fetch new tracks in Spotify. This info message probably relates to that limit but it could also be what iKenndac writes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same. When I skip too much through the tracks, it prints out an Information Message "Rate limited waiting 3s".

But maybe they should print out a message in the UI ?
Otherwise it will confuse the unexperienced users.